# Float Left not working for div blocks

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know why the `float:left` isn't working?  Basically, I have a `div` with `class=boxscore_first`, which is in the correct position.  Then I have two more `divs` with `class=boxscore` which are appearing on top of the first.  I want them to appear in sequence to the right of the first one.  I want them to all `float` next to each other..

### HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="scoreboard"></div>
    <div class="boxscore_first"></div>
    <div class="boxscore"></div>
    <div class="boxscore"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.boxscore_first {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:-60px;
    margin-left:13px;
    float:left;
}

.boxscore {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-60px;
    margin-left:13px;
}
```

Comment: So you want the floating divs to float next to each other? Or what? Please provide an image to further explain what you want, and a jsFiddle.

Comment: Yes I want all three to float next to each other..

Comment: If one div is floating, and you want the others to be next to it, you are going to have to float "against" them. Add float: left; to the others.

Comment: Never mind.  I just used dispLay: inline-block

Comment: Then please answer you own question with your solution to help out others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, according to HTML you provided, you have three boxes. Left one and right one are `.boxscore_first` and the middle one is `.boxscore`.

Another and **more relevant** thing is that the `.boxscore_first` is a div. That means it's a **block element**. It doesn't float. In other words *it wants to be alone in the line*. You have to make both `.boxscore_first` and `.boxscore` `float: left`.

Comment: Ya sorry the third one should be boxscore

Comment: I corrected the question and the code.  Can you please take another look.